# Bootstrap: how to change width of container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the width of container. I am using following code:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container{
max-width:  620px;
}

}



@media(min-width:992px){

.container{
max-width:  620px;
}
}



@media(min-width:768px){

.container{
max-width:  620px;
}
```

When the size of the browser starts from 750px the width of .container inheritances the default width of bootstrap.

How can I solve this issue? There is another better way to reach my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to change Less/Sass variable value and recompile styles or use [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Comment: I never changed Less/Sass variable in Bootstrap...How can I do it?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
This is official ;) Find your component and mix it like you want it. Quite usefull but sometimes takes some time when your frontend is not fully completed and you may need some changes in the future too.

Comment: getbootstrap.com/customize is definitely the fastest way to customize